# AutoPostBack=True causing form to fire Page_Load event more than once

Tags: asp.net

I have a DropDownList with an `SelectedIndexChanged` event listener

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="LoanOptionCombo" runat="server" AutoProstBack="True">
```

Listener

```
Protected Sub LoanOptionCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LoanOptionCombo.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' hello world, no code here yet
End Sub
```

My `Page_Load` event

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' parse a .txt file and populate the DropDownList
    InitializeLoanOptions()
End Sub
```

When the form initially loads, the loan options are loaded into the DropDownList (currently 4).

Whenever the user selects a loan option for the DropDownList, the DrowDownList gets re-initialized somehow, adding the same 4 options to the list again.

Each time the user selects another option, the same 4 options are re-added to the list.

I'm assuming the Page_Load event is being called again because that's the only place where I'm actually adding the DropDownList items.  No other place in code interacts with the DrowDownList.Items.

**How can I listen to the SelectedIndexChanged event on my DropDownList but avoid re-initializing my whole form?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your `Page_Load` as below

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' parse a .txt file and populate the DropDownList
 If Not IsPostBack
    InitializeLoanOptions()
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This will be the accepted answer as it has code example. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsPostBack property in page load event.
Only data bind to your drop down when your page is load.

check theses links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/if-not-page-ispostback/

Answer (score 0):

Check IsPostBack property on page_load.

```
If Not IsPostBack
  // Load your drop drop list here....
End If
```